# Strange error with stream_context_set_option

Tags: php, ssl, pem

I wanted to connect ssl Server. And I attached ssl certificate with stream_context_set_option.

But it returns `"check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate".`

```
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 
                          dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$apnsCert);
```

apns-dev.pem is in same folder.

If I add,  on the top, it works well. I don't understand.
Certificate file's permission is 644